# Sum of Bernoulli variables expectation composed in ReLU function

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Assuming $n$ independent random variables $g_i \in \lbrace0,1\rbrace$,
which takes the value 1 with probability of $p_i$.

Asumming $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ , how can I calculate the following expectation ?

$$ E_{g_i} [\max (0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_ig_i)]$$

Is it possible to approximate or to bound the above with the Poisson destitution?
what will be the $\lambda$ in such case ?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this can be calculated in any sort of nice fashion.

Comment: Bounded below by $0$ and also by $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i$  and above by $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \max(0,x_i)$, which is no more than  $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n p_i |x_i|$